# Run on server option not appearing in Eclipse when right clicking on a .jsp file

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

[Run on server not appearing when I right click on a . jsp file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdJbj.png), but when [I right click on the folder it show Run on Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cTwy.png), but I get a 404 ERROR.

**What I'm using:**

- Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java
- Java 8 / 1.8 JRE
- Tomcat 9
- MySQL

**What I done so far:**

- Delete Eclipse from my computer entirely and reinstalled Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java developers
- Deleted Tomcat 9 from server on Eclipse and re-added it.
- [Edited my Project Facet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU6Jh.png) and have Dynamic Web Module Turned On
- Checked my Java Build Path

**I figured out the issue**

- My directory was messed up this is [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdJbj.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WY6K.png) so it didnt recognized the web content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSP file is not in the deployed `WebContent` folder. It can't be Run on the Server from where it is.

Comment: yup i fixed it, Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by web content?